# How to access app's routes inside app engine cron job?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-app-engine-python

So I have the routes defined for my app inside `main.py`, something like:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/',          handler=HomePage,       name="home")
])
```

Inside the cron job I can't seem to access the routes of the app, for example this doesn't work:

```
self.uri_for('home')
```

I found somewhere online a snippet that fixes it, but it's ugly to use:

```
cls.app.router.add(r)
```

Where `r` would be an array of routes.

Is there a way to have acces to the app's routes inside an app engine cron job?

Answer (score 2):

Your example is incorrect, it seems to be a cross between [simple routes](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#simple-routes) and [extended routes](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#extended-routes).

To be able to use `self.uri_for('home')` you need to use named routes, i.e. extended routes:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(r'/', handler=HomePage, name='home'),
])
```

With that in place `self.uri_for('home')` *should* work, assuming `self` is a [`webapp2.RequestHandler`](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.RequestHandler) instance.

The workaround just looks ugly, but that is pretty much what [`uri_for`](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.RequestHandler.uri_for) does [under the hood](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/webapp2.html#RequestHandler.uri_for) as well:

```
def uri_for(self, _name, *args, **kwargs):
    """Returns a URI for a named :class:`Route`.

    .. seealso:: :meth:`Router.build`.
    """
    return self.app.router.build(self.request, _name, args, kwargs)
```